# How to insert an array in the middle of an array?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby array `[1, 4]`. I want to insert another array `[2, 3]` in the middle so that it becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I can achieve that with `[1, 4].insert(1, [2, 3]).flatten`, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly means “in the middle”? Given `[1,1,4,4]` input, should `[2,3]` be inserted where?

Comment: "Where" should be a variable. I want to be able to insert in the beginning or anywhere in the middle, but not at the end (which can be easily achieved with array1 + array2).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do it the following way.

```
[1,4].insert(1,*[2,3])
```

The [`insert()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) method handles multiple parameters. Therefore you can convert your array to parameters with the splat operator `*`.

Comment: All answers I got are great, but I think yours are the easiest to read. Thanks!

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that `[1,4].insert(2,*[2,3]) #=>  [1,4,2,3]`, which allows the elements of the second array to be inserted after the last element of the first array.

Answer (score 5):

One form of the method [Array#[]=](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) takes two arguments, `index` and `length`. When the latter is zero and the rvalue is an array, the method inserts the elements of the rvalue into the receiver *before* the element at the given index (and returns the rvalue). Therefore, to insert the elements of:

```
b = [2,3]
```

into:

```
a = [1,4]
```

before the element at index `1` (`4`), we write:

```
a[1,0] = b
  #=> [2,3]
a #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Note:

```
a=[1,4]
a[0,0] = [2,3]
a #=> [2,3,1,4]

a=[1,4]
a[2,0] = [2,3]
a #=> [1,4,2,3]

a=[1,4]
a[4,0] = [2,3]
a #=> [1,4,nil,nil,2,3]]
```

which is why the insertion location is before the given index.

Comment: This is a very concise way to insert another array's elements. Maybe you should add some explanation (and some whitespace).

Answer (score 3):

```
def insert_array receiver, pos, other
  receiver.insert pos, *other
end

insert_array [1, 4], 1, [2, 3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or, the above might be achieved by monkeypatching the `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def insert_array pos, other
    insert pos, *other
  end
end
```

I believe, this is short enough notation to have any additional syntax sugar. BTW, flattening the result is not a good idea, since it will corrupt an input arrays, already having arrays inside:

```
[1, [4,5]].insert 1, *[2,3]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, [4,5]]
```

but:

```
[1, [4,5]].insert(1, [2,3]).flatten
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

**My option without array#insert method**

```
array = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
new_array = [4,5]

array[0...array.size/2] + new_array + array[array.size/2..-1]
```